# Can I send out a multicast packet through a dedicated NIC by Windows command?

Tags: windows, multicast

There are 2 NICs in my Windows-based machine, the IP address of one of NICs is 192.168.1.x/24 and the other one is 192.168.2.x/24. The Windows-based machine run an application that need to send out the multicast packet 229.255.10.1 through two of the NIC. However, the multicast packet 229.255.10.1 can be sent out from the NIC 192.168.1.x/24 only. Can I use route add -p Windows Command to send out the multicast packet from the NIC 192.168.2.x/24?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
route -p add 229.255.10.1 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.2.x metric 1
```

where 192.168.2.x is your IP on nic 2

It remains only a problem that I haven't found a solution yet: if your application send a packet before you add the root, you need to reboot PC. This is a problem if the second NIC is, for example, a VPN client and it starts after the application